# Codeigniter email 550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to send emails using codeigniter,
this is the code i'm using,

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://sub5.mail.xxxxxxxx.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'account@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => FALSE
        ); 

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->clear(TRUE);

$this->email->from($datadatay['hcusemail'], 'FMF Refund Form Data');
$this->email->to("eranga.p@xxxxx.lk");
$this->email->cc("eranga.xxxx@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject("Refund Form");
$this->email->message("The form is attached hereby");
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");

$this->email->attach($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/dist/pdf/' . $filename);


$this->email->send();
```

this code works perfectly fine in localhost. but when it published in server, I get below error,

```
220 homiemail-a119.g.dreamhost.com ESMTP
<br /><pre>hello: 250-homiemail-a119.g.dreamhost.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 40960000
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 8BITMIME
</pre><pre>from: 250 2.1.0 Ok
</pre><pre>to: 250 2.1.5 Ok
</pre><pre>to: 250 2.1.5 Ok
</pre><pre>data: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
</pre>550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed. Please read: http://dhurl.org/20b D157
<br />The following SMTP error was encountered: 550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed. Please read: http://dhurl.org/20b D157
<br />Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2017 16:50:59 +0530
From: &quot;FMF Refund Form Data&quot; &lt;erangainfo@gmail.com&gt;
Return-Path: &lt;erangainfo@gmail.com&gt;
To: eranga.p@findmyfare.lk
Cc: eranga.findmyfare@gmail.com
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Refund_Form?=
Reply-To: &quot;erangainfo@gmail.com&quot; &lt;erangainfo@gmail.com&gt;
X-Sender: erangainfo@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: &lt;587f4f9b1ea8f@gmail.com&gt;
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=&quot;B_ATC_587f4f9b1eb0f&quot;

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ATC_587f4f9b1eb0f
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=&quot;B_ALT_587f4f9b1ead4&quot;

--B_ALT_587f4f9b1ead4
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

The form is attached hereby


--B_ALT_587f4f9b1ead4
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

The form is attached hereby

--B_ALT_587f4f9b1ead4--

--B_ATC_587f4f9b1eb0f
Content-type: application/x-unknown-content-type; name=&quot;eranga.docx&quot;
Content-Disposition: attachment;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

--B_ATC_587f4f9b1eb0f--</pre>
```

Tried lots of things, but nothing works. Please help.

Comment: go through  [link](http://dhurl.org/20b)  in the above error messageand sort out the problem

Comment: @Deep3015 thank you very much for the response. but that url is nothing. it shows only   _This is the DreamHost URL shortener._

Comment: Above link goes to [link](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215036118) .check it

Comment: Thanks. I read it and it explains. Thank you very much. @Deep3015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you try to send a letter from a domain that is not yours.

As can be seen from the log, you send email from `erangainfo@gmail.com`.
But you send it via `ssl://sub5.mail.xxxxxxxx.com` server that is obviously not `gmail.com`. You spoof sender's address. Dreamhost prevents it, hence the error.

Comment: Yeah.. That was exactly the the issue. Corrected it. now it's working fine. Thanks a lot @vaviloff .